# When is this group compact?

Tags: matrices, group-theory, lie-groups, compactness

Let $K=\begin{pmatrix}
I_a & 0\\
0 & -I_b
\end{pmatrix}$, where a+b=n, and $I_a$ is the $a\times a$ identity matrix and similar definition for $I_b$. Let G be the group consisting of all complex $n\times n$ matrices such that $A^*KA=K$. For what values of a and b is G compact?

If $a=0$ or $b=0$, this just reduces to the unitary group, which is compact. However, if $n=2$ and $a=b=1$, then $A=\begin{pmatrix}
c & \sqrt{c^2-1}\\
\sqrt{c^2-1} & c
\end{pmatrix}$ is not bounded and in G. Is there a way to generalize this?

Comment: What are $p$ and $q$? A quick result is that $|\det(A)|=1$.

Comment: Sorry, they are supposed to be a and b.

Answer (score 8):

This groups is known as the [indefinite unitary group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_group#Indefinite_forms), and it is not compact unless $a=0$ or $b=0$. One can show this in the general case almost as easily as the $a=b=1$ case, using a subset of matrices such as the subgroup
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\cosh(\psi) &  & &  & \sinh(\psi) \\
 & 1 & & &  \\
 & & \ddots & & \\
 & & & 1 & \\
\sinh(\psi) & & & & \cosh(\psi)
\end{bmatrix}\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \psi\in\mathbb{R}
$$
which are not bounded in $\mathbb{C}^{n^2}$.